# Competing Trx in an uncle

Tags: transactions, uncle-blocks

How does Ethereum handle the integration of an uncle Block? Because, as far as I understand, there could be the possibility that an uncle contains a transaction, which compets with a transaction from a valid block.Thus the mempool of every Miner differs from another, right?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Related: [What happens to transactions in uncles](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16538/what-happens-to-transactions-in-uncles)

Answer (score 1):

Transaction in an uncle are ignored, if they are valid they may already be included in a parent block, or can be mined in a future block.

Only the header of an uncle block is included in the blockchain. From the [Ethereum Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf%22Ethereum%20Yellow%20Paper%22) section 4.3 The Block.

> 4.3. The  Block.
>
> The  block  in  Ethereum  is  the  collection of relevant pieces of information (known as the block header), **H**, together with information  corresponding to the  comprised  transactions, **T**,  and  a  set  of  other  block headers **U** that are known to have a parent equal to the
>   present block’s parent’s parent (such blocks are known as *ommers*).